# Transforming Simplex Map for UV mapping on a sphere

Tags: python, three.js, map-projections, uv-mapping, simplex-noise

I would like to dynamically generate a simplex-based image that will map nicely on a sphere in three.js, however I'm having problems with distortion at the poles. Here is the initial map code:

```
def generate_map(seed,width=WIDTH,height=HEIGHT,xoffset=0.0,yoffset=0.0,zoom=1.0):
    """ Return a simple matrix of simplex noise from 0-255."""
    mapdata = []
    random.seed(seed)
    zoom=zoom * 100.0
    for x in xrange(height):
        row=[]
        for y in xrange (width):
            xparam=merc_x(float((x+xoffset)/zoom))
            yparam=merc_y(float((y+yoffset)/zoom))
            noisevalue=snoise2(xparam, yparam,  NOISEOCTAVES, 0.52,2.0, height/zoom*2, width/zoom, float(seed) )
            #convert 1.0...-1.0 to 255...0
            pixel=int((noisevalue+1)/2*PIXEL_DEPTH-1)
            cell={'height': pixel, 'x':x, 'y':y }

            row.append( cell )
        mapdata.append(row)

    return mapdata
```

This generates data which creates a map that tiles sideways, but not at the top and bottom (which is ideal).

[image: world map]

The problem arises when this is mapped on a sphere in three.js:

```
return new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map:         THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/worldmap.png?seed='+seed),
    })
);
```

You end up with pinching near the poles due to UVMapping that takes place:

[image: mapped on sphere].

I suspect the simplest way to solve the pinching issues is to use a mercator transformation on the source image, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to implement it.

Does anyone have any suggestions? The full source of the project can be found [here](https://github.com/CityGenerator/Megacosm-Generator) if you want to give it a try.

Update:
Looking at the handy [UV Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:UVMapping.png) graph on wikipedia in combination with the [Three.JS sphere mapping example](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_uv_tests.html), I think these are a good place to start...

Comment: google "perlin noise on a sphere". example: http://www.clicktorelease.com/code/perlin/chrome.html

Comment: The problem with most of those examples is that I still need a flat map for other parts of the application, hence I can't skip that step and go straight to 3d simplex noise.